# C# / WPF - DesignData - Binding to DesignData Collection Properties

Tags: c#, wpf

I like design time data, especially when creating small widgets. For this very simple use case I'm having trouble binding to the properties of a design-time list which I have created in xaml.

Please find my ViewModel, View and SampleData below;

**ViewModel**

```
internal class SummaryViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public IList<Person> PersonList { get; set; }

    internal SummaryViewModel()
    {
        PersonList = new List<Person>();
    }
}
```

**Sample Data**

```
<ViewModel:SummaryViewModel xmlns:ViewModel="ViewModel" Title="Test Title">
    <ViewModel:SummaryViewModel.Connections>
        <ViewModel:ConnectionViewModel Id="0" />
        <ViewModel:ConnectionViewModel Id="1" />
    </ViewModel:SummaryViewModel.Connections> 
</ViewModel:SummaryViewModel>
```

**View**

```
<StackPanel x:Class="View.SummaryView"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            d:DesignHeight="100" 
            d:DesignWidth="100"
            d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=/DesignData/SampleSummaryViewModel.xaml}"

            Orientation="Vertical"
            Background="LightGreen">

    <!-- This Works -->
    <Label FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold" Content="{Binding Title}" />

    <!-- This Works -->
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}" />

    <!-- This DOESN'T work -->
    <Label FontSize="8" Content="{Binding PersonList, Path=Count}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**How would you configure SampleData such that you could bind to the Count of a list specified therein?**

I have tried setting the resource type as both `DesignData` and `DesignDataWithDesignTimeCreatableTypes` with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
<Label FontSize="8" Content="{Binding Path=PersonList.Count}"/>
```

Also Mårten is correct, you should use an ObservableCollection instead.

HTH

Comment: I had to wait a whole nother 36 seconds, there are so many caveats to using this site if you're new.

Answer (score 2):

CityView, just as a side note: to debug DataBinding I usually use an empty converter which only returns the value it was given. I put a breakpoint in there and that way I can see what exactly is going back and forth.

```
public class BindTestConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Combined with that and what the Output window tells me usually leads me to a solution to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

It should work, but become a one-time binding since your list does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and therefore the binding is not updated when `Count` changes.

Try using an `ObservableCollection<Person>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I just gave it a go and unfortunately this doesn't work either. I should add that it's not that I get '0' displayed, the binding fails completely and no text is displayed at all. I don't know how to debug binding failures in the Designer view...

Comment: Ah, sorry I read your code wrong. The binding should be: {Binding Path=PersonList.Count}